# makemenu config equivalent for windows

Tags: windows, linux, bare-metal

Is there any make menuconfig like utility for windows ? I have a software stack for baremental embedded systems that needs some configuration before building (build environment is under windows but uses makefiles).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [WIX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). As far as I know it has GUI builder written with Qt that will ask you to set up all necessary parameters.